# I am having an error with Flutter saying: Controller's length property does not match

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have been having this issue in Flutter when I am trying to use the DefaultTabController() widget but it seems it does not work the way I have specified the layout. Can anyone help me with it.

This is my code:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        initialIndex: 0,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {}),
            title: Text('Home'),
            bottom: TabBar(tabs: [
              Tab(child: Text("Videos")),
              Tab(child: Text("Live Videos")),
              Tab(child: Text("Gallery")),
            ]),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              new Card(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *body* element only contains one element. According to your length attribute of the DefaultTabController, there should be 3 elements in that array.

```
body: TabBarView(
    children: [
        new Card(
            color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        new Card(
            color: Colors.red,
        ),
        new Card(
            color: Colors.orange,
        ),
    ],
),
```